# int() function in awk changes the argument even if this is integer already

Tags: awk, integer, rounding, logarithm, natural-logarithm

I don't understand the following two results in `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
  print    (log(.01)/log(10))
  print int(log(.01)/log(10))
}'
-2
-1
```

Version:

```
$ awk --version 
GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.1.2)
```

Comment: even though the mathematical result is an integer, the value `log(.01)` is for sure a real as it represents the natural logarithm. On top of that, there are floating-point approximations which make `log(0.01)` to be slightly different numerically then mathematically. Dito for `log(10)`. Ergo, the division will not be perfect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is more than meets the eye:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
  printf "%.16f\n", log(.01)/log(10)
}'
-1.9999999999999996
```

Comment: So what format does `awk` use by default? `"%.6f\n"`?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis It's defined in the `OFMT` variable (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#OFMT), which defaults to `%.6g`.